# Vimのプラグインjedi-vimの補完が正常に動かない

Tags: python, python3, vim, anaconda3

#### 前提・実現したいこと

- jedi-vimのオムニ補完を正常に作動させたい

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

- Vundleを使用し、jedi-vimを導入しました
- `str.`や`numpy.`で補完を試したところ、以下のメッセージが出ます

`-- オムニ補完 (^O^N^P) パターンは見つかりませんでした`

#### 該当のソースコード

test.py

```
import numpy
numpy. #この時点でエラーメッセージ
```

~/.vimrc

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

#### 試したこと

- vimで`:help jedi-vim`を打つとjedi-vimのヘルプ画面は表示されました
- 一度Vundleを削除し、dein.vimでも試しましたが同じようなエラーがでました

#### 補足情報

- VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1
- anaconda3-5.3.0（pyenvで管理）

---

足りない情報がありましたら追記いたしますのでご教授お願いいたします。
よろしくお願いします。

#### 追記

書くの忘れてました。マルチポストしてます。
https://teratail.com/questions/163424

Comment: 私も同様の現象です。 HomeBrewでインストールしたVim8
Vundleでjedi-vimをインストールしたが、
pythonのファイルを開いて、str. numpy.　入力しても
「オムニ補完　パターンがありません」と表示される。 homebreのvim8は、vim上で次のコマンドを入力し（ :python3 print(sys.version)）
でpython3.7を使用していることが確認できました。 vim8とjedi-vimとpython3.7では互換性がなく対応できていないのでしょうか？ ちなみに、macosのシステム上のvim7.4を使用すると成功します。
こちらは、python2.7を使用していました。

Comment: 関連issue?: [Auto complete not working](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/845) ／ [jedi-vim is not aware of pyenv path](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/869)

Comment: もし分かれば、jedi-vim のバージョンを追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: 似た質問が別質問として新しく投稿されました。[vim8でjed-vimが使用できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51304/19110)

Answer (score 2):

動作にはいくつかの前提条件を満たす必要があるようなので、これらを念のため確認してみてください。

- Vimが`+python`または`+python3`フラグを有効にしてコンパイルされている。
  例えばLinuxならコマンドラインから`vim --version | grep python`を実行して、上記のいずれかが含まれているかを確認。`-python`のように`-`が付いているとNG。
- Pythonの`jedi`ライブラリがインストールされている。

  ```
  $ pip install jedi
  ```

参考：
[davidhalter/jedi-vim: Using the jedi autocompletion library for VIM.](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim)
[Vimメモ : jedi-vimでPythonの入力補完 - もた日記](https://wonderwall.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/01/29/213052)

Comment: ありがとうございます。どちらも確認しましてjediライブラリはインストール済み、pythonは`+python3`でした。